# Getting started with awesomium c++ with visual studio 2012

Tags: c++, awesomium

I just downloaded `awesomium sdk` for c++. I'm done configuring it with visual studio. But when I try running examples from there site, I keep getting this error

> (C:\Program Files
> (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(1177,5):
> error MSB3191: Unable to create directory
> "c:\users\kartsali\documents\visual studio
> 2012\Projects\sample\Debug\sample.exeC:\Program Files (x86)\Awesomium
> Technologies LLC\Awesomium SDK\1.7.5.0\build".
>
> The given path's format is not supported.

Where did I go wrong in configuration?

Answer (score 0):

After installing windows SDK :
When you launch awesomium.NET samples (windows touch + awes...) it's open Visual studio, now in the solution explorer try to build CORE=>C++>Awesomium.
Normally it's should works. If it doesn't you have done a bad installation au the SDK (version ? ) => ( Work’s for me with visual 12, windows 8.1 on a surface pro without a special manipulation/configuration)

after this test, you could start some practice exercises with the sdk .

(for including lib i use CMAKE to build visualstudio project, works great with awesomium )

Pegaz